# C++ std::sort a vector of share_ptr<objects>

Tags: c++, vector

How can I sort a vector of shared_ptrs C++? I'm trying to sort a vector a share_ptrs of struct data object. And the comparator function is also defined.

```
struct data{
  int number;
};

bool comparator(const std::shared_ptr<data> &a, const std::shared_ptr<data> &b) {
    return a->number < b->number();
}

int main() {
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<data>> v;
  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comparator);
}
```

But I got compile error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/algorithm:62:0,
                 from test.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::__insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<data>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<data> > >; _Compare = bool (*)(const A&, const A&)]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:2226:70:   required from ‘void std::__final_insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<data>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<data> > >; _Compare = bool (*)(const A&, const A&)]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:5491:55:   required from ‘void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<data>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<data> > >; _Compare = bool (*)(const A&, const A&)]’
test.cpp:110:45:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:2159:29: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const A&’ from expression of type ‘std::shared_ptr<data>’
.....
```

Comment: `b->number();` <- Get rid of the parenthesis. Then [it works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49c391d12679a140).

Comment: bad parenthesis in comparator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> return a->number < b->number();
> ```

Must be:

```
return a->number < b->number;
```

However, I wonder if this is your real code and which compiler you are using. You should get much clearer error messages, for example:

Visual C++ 2013:

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
```

GCC v4.8.3:

```
error: expression cannot be used as a function
     return a->number < b->number();
                                  ^
```

---

P.S.: You should post your complete code with all `#include`s when asking such questions. In your case, `<vector>`, `<algorithm>` and `<memory>`.